# request with single ip or dnsname to multi node docker swarm cluster

Tags: docker, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm, internal-load-balancer

I want to make the High available service. However, I don't know how to make requests to cluster services with single ip or dns name from outside the cluster.

I tried --endpoint-mode dnsrr. But I think this is not for the outside request balancing. Must I use reverse proxy or external load balancer. Can I make with software and cheap. I wish help me. Thank you.

Comment: Ingress will be running on every node of the cluster. Each of these ingress will load balance the requests to all nodes. If you need to have a single entry point, you have to use a reverse proxy to pass it to the ingress endpoints. You can use haproxy, or nginx for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--publish-add` argument of [`docker service update`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/) command in order to map port of docker swarm service to host VM port. Then access the service using the host ip and port.

You can also [create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/) the service with published port using `--publish host_vm_port:service_port` syntax.
For example:

```
docker service create --name my_web --replicas 3 --publish 8080:80 nginx
```

would create docker swarm service nginx with 3 replicas with nginx port 80 mapped to host VM 8080 port. Then you software client can access the service using [vm_ip:80/service_url] url

Comment: I understand. 
But My problem is VMs shared ip , VMs load balancing. Like this photo :https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/images/ingress-lb.png
Can I run reverse proxy in docker. Or Can I fix with Domain name

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but depending on your setup you might be able to use [keepalived](https://github.com/acassen/keepalived). It allows you to define a static, virtual IP that will always point to one of your machines as long as there is still one running.